# There is some problem with null character termination in this code

Tags: c, while-loop, undefined-behavior, string-literals, strcpy

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char *str = (char*)malloc(4);

    strcpy(str,"aaab");

    char *pt;
    strcpy(pt,str);

    while(pt != NULL){
        printf("%c",*pt);
        pt++;
    }
}
```

I wanted this code to just print out the str string but instead it gave me the string and some bizzare output.The thing just gets better as the pattern keeps changing. I think the problem is with null character `'\0'` termination.

[This is the code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7YOf.png).

Comment: You cannot program by trial and error. It is obvious that you are just guessing, that's not how programming works. You need to actually study how strings and null termination works before using it, you can't learn that by trial and error.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with the shown code.

The first one is that the string literal `"aaab"` contains `5` characters (including the terminating zero character `'\0'`) instead of `4`. So the call of `strcpy` that expects as the second argument a pointer to a string

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(4);

strcpy(str,"aaab");
```

invokes undefined behavior because the destination dynamically allocated memory is not large enough to store `5` characters.

You need to allocate one more byte to store the string

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(5);
```

In this code snippet

```
char *pt;
strcpy(pt,str);
```

there is used the uninitialized pointer `pt` and as a result again the call of `strcpy` invokes undefined behavior.

You could write for example

```
char s[5];
char *pt = s;

strcpy(pt,str);
```

And this while loop has undefined behavior even if the pointer `pt` would be initialized

```
while(pt != NULL){
    printf("%c",*pt);
    pt++;
}
```

Instead you should compare not the pointer itself with `NULL` but the character pointed to by the pointer with the terminating zero character `'\0'` like

```
while(*pt != '\0'){
    printf("%c",*pt);
    pt++;
}
```

Of course the pointer `pt` shall point to a string.

Pay attention that you should free the allocated memory when it is not required any more

```
free( str );
```

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I copied and pasted this code snippet forgetting to change it though in comments described the problem.:)

Comment: It does help changing `NULL` to `'\0'` , also is strcpy() the only way to intialize mallocked strings

Comment: @KiyotakaAyanakoji The function malloc does not initialize allocated memory. On the other hand, the function calloc initializes allocated memory with zeroes. So to store a string in an allocated memory you need to copy it there.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy(str,"aaab")
```

1. You're trying to write 5 bytes to a location you allocated 4 bytes for. Recall that the C strings are terminated with a null-byte, and the valid indexing range is from 0 to n - 1.

```
char *ptr;
```

2. This only allocated memory for the pointer. The contents of the pointer are indeterminate, i.e. they may be pointing to anything and accessing the memory pointed to by the pointer invokes undefined behaviour. You need to allocate memory for the pointed-to data before trying to copy something to it.
3. Do not cast the result of `malloc()`. `malloc()` and family returns a generic `void *` that is implicitly converted to any other pointer type. The cast is redundant and just clutters the code.
4. Check the return value of `malloc()`. It returns a `NULL` pointer constant to indicate failure.
5. Compare `p`'s pointee to the null-byte, not the `NULL` pointer constant.

```
// while (p != NULL) {
} 

while (*p != `\0`) {
}
```

Or simply;

```
while (*p) {
}
```

Otherwise, your code would invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When `malloc(4);` is used like this, it provides only 4 bytes, but for \0 character at least one more byte is required.
So I suggest to use

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(5);
```

But more solid solution is to count length of source string, add 1 to this value and allocate memory for destination string. E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *s1 = "aaab";
    char *s2 = (char*)malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);

    strcpy(s2, s1);

    printf(">%s<", s2);
}
```

Comment: And avoid casting the result of `malloc` to `char*`.